# Amazon S3 Index.html over https

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, https, document-root

I setup an S3 bucket named www-example-com which contains an index.html file. The bucket is configured as "Enable website hosting" with an "Index Document" named index.html

I'm able to get the index.html file working by using 
  http://{bucket-name}.s3-{aws-region}.amazonaws.com

However this syntax does not support HTTPS

Yet I'm able to access my bucket over HTTPS using
  https://s3.amazonaws.com/{bucket-name}

However this url does not support an index.html file.

Examples are:

1. `http://www-example-com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` **works**
2. `https://www-example-com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` **does
   NOT work**
3. `https://s3.amazonaws.com/www-example-com/` **does NOT work**
4. `https://s3.amazonaws.com/www-example-com/index.html` **works**

Is there any way in S3 to get the index.html file working in conjunction with HTTPS?

Comment: URL 3 and 4 are not possible using S3

Comment: Check this other stack overflow post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719764/https-for-amazon-s3-static-website

Comment: The *only* way to do this using all-AWS services is detailed in the answers to the question linked by @JimP. as well as other answers here on SO: CloudFront hosting the SSL, in front of the bucket.  Note that when you set this up, [type in the web site endpoint hostname in the CloudFront origin configuration, don't select it from the drop-down list](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-create-cfdist.html).  S3 website hosting does not directly support SSL.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the above linked question. It is a duplicate of this (also unanswered) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280836/aws-s3-virtual-host-ssl-does-not-serve-index-page#13280944